# Most efficient way to dedupe 2 arrays by value A and sort by value B?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, merge

I have an array containing objects that have an identifier and the sort value. When an endpoint I'm querying returns an array with the updated objects, I need to merge it with the existing array, the incoming array's duplicated identifier objects taking precedence over the existing array but for them both to be sorted alongside each other. e.g

```
arrayA = [A:1, B:4, C:6]

arrayB = [D:2, A:3, C:5, G:7]

result = [D:2, A:3, B:4, C:5, G:7]
```

So far I can't think of any solution that doesn't include me deduping the arrays first and sorting them second, which seems wildly inefficient for the long lists that I am going to be working with. What would be the most efficient way of going about this?

Comment: "seems inefficient" seems questionable ;) Code your algorithm, measure it and find out if it actually needs optimization. Most probably it won't.

Comment: @georg I didn't study CS so this seems scary. But essentially I am thinking of filtering arrayA element by element, looking for elements with same ID in arrayB at each iteration. That's what looks to me to be the inefficient part. Perhaps there is a better way of going about that... ?

Comment: I see. On modern hardware everything less than few thousand cycles should be done in milliseconds. So even an "inefficient" algorithm can actually work just fine. How big are your arrays?

Comment: @georg Not too massive, at most 3k-4k items long. There is potential for data to come in often however, and keeping our frames under 16ms is important.

Comment: Efficient in lines of code? CPU time? Memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform the usual merge step that mergesort uses, except you can skip elements in `arrayA` that are already in `arrayB`. To perform this check quickly, you can first add all the ids from `arrayB` to a `Set`. This will result in a final runtime of *O(n + m)* (with extra space for the `Set`) instead of *O((n + m) log(n + m)*:

```js
function linearMerge(A, B) {
  const res = [];
  const newIds = new Set(B.map(o => o.id));
  A = A.filter(o => !newIds.has(o.id));

  let i = 0, j = 0;
  while (i < A.length && j < B.length) {
    if (A[i].val < B[j].val) res.push(A[i++]);
    else res.push(B[j++]);
  }
  while (i < A.length) res.push(A[i++]);
  while (j < B.length) res.push(B[j++]);
  return res;
}

const arrayA = [{id: 'A', val: 1}, {id: 'B', val: 4}, {id: 'C', val: 6}];
const arrayB = [{id: 'D', val: 2}, {id: 'A', val: 3}, {id: 'C', val: 5}, {id: 'G', val: 7}];

const result = linearMerge(arrayA, arrayB);
console.log(result); // [D:2, A:3, B:4, C:5, G:7]
```

Of course, your original approach also works but can be improved if you use a `Set` to remove duplicates:

```js
function nLogNMerge(A, B) {
  const newIds = new Set(B.map(o => o.id));
  return [...A.filter(o => !newIds.has(o.id)), ...B]
    .sort((a, b) => a.val - b.val);
}

const arrayA = [{id: 'A', val: 1}, {id: 'B', val: 4}, {id: 'C', val: 6}];
const arrayB = [{id: 'D', val: 2}, {id: 'A', val: 3}, {id: 'C', val: 5}, {id: 'G', val: 7}];

const result = nLogNMerge(arrayA, arrayB);
console.log(result); // [D:2, A:3, B:4, C:5, G:7]
```

---

I tested both approaches where `arrayA` and `arrayB` have 4500 entries, and the linear merge indeed outperforms the second approach (about "20%" faster). You can find the test here: https://jsperf.com/merge-sorted-arrays-with-duplicates/1

Comment: This is an awesome reply. Thanks!